# Chrome inapp purchase test

Tags: google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement an inapp purchase for my Chrome Extension. I have followed the guide on https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap, added 1 buyable item and implemented following code on an onclick event:

```
google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails({
        'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
        'success': onSkuDetails,
        'failure': onSkuDetailsFail
    });
var onSkuDetails = function (response) {
    console.log("onSkuDetails", response);
    /*var products = response.response.details.inAppProducts;
    var count = products.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var product = products[i];
        addProductToUI(product);
    }

    getLicenses();*/
}

var onSkuDetailsFail = function(result){
    console.log("onSkuDetailsFailed", result);
}
```

But every time I click it, I get

> onSkuDetailsFailed > "INVALID_RESPONSE_ERROR"

I have added the buy.js and changed some permissions, but still don't see where the problem might be.

Do note, that I'm testing this extension locally and not from the Chrome webstore using my own account and a friend's account which I included as testperson on the dashboard.

Comment: Try checking if your [region](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/pricing#seller) is supported by the store. As mentioned in a related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32303923/5995040), they've changed their test environment to a supported country to continue testing their in-app purchase. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm from Belgium, which is listed, so that shouldn't be the problem? I've tried using a US proxy on Chrome, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Same is happening for me.